# Does such a JSON string builder exist?

Tags: java, json

I'm looking to do something like the following in Java and was wondering whether such a JSON library/helper already existed out there somewhere?

```
SomeJsonBuilder builder = new SomeJsonBuilder();
builder.add("one", "oneValue");
builder.add("two.three", "threeValue");
String output = builder.toString();
```

Such that the output string above would be something like:

```
{"one":"oneValue", "two":{"three":"threeValue"}}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: I'd disagree... that SO question is a general question about JSON libraries. This one is pretty specific (although I would have phrased as `builder.add("one", "oneValue"); builder.add("two.three", "threeValue");`

Comment: oops, yes you're right Jason.  In my haste to write the post, I made that mistake.  Thanks for the pick up.

Comment: "two.three" is a valid key in JSON objects.  Not every collection in JSON is an object.  I don't think I'd like a JSON builder that doesn't let me use arrays or objects with dotted names.

json-lib's fluid interface: `builder.key("two").object().key("three").value("threeValue").endObject();`

doesn't seem *that* cumbersome anyway.

Comment: good point - thanks.  Would replacing the dots (.) with colons (:) get around that?

Comment: @digiarnie, no.  Colons can be in valid keys too.

Comment: underscore-java has U.objectBuilder().add("key", "value").toJson().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked [JSONLib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html)? It doesn't do exactly what you're looking for though. But it is close.

Comment: The map function is probably the closest.  Thanks ninja!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: I've had a look at the classes there but I don't think I see a class that accepts the kind of notation I'm after.  They all seem to want to build up objects before toString'ing.  Ideally I'd like a utility that takes in the notation I mentioned in my post (I've already this utility but of course it'd be nice if there was one that was well tested  and used already)

Comment: Maven coordinate: `org.json:json`.

Answer (score 1):

Not straightforward, but I'd combine JAXB, Jackson and BeanUtils.

Here's one part
http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/jaxb-json-jackson-howto.texy

Here's the other...
http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/expression/DefaultResolver.html

Answer (score 1):

Just came across your question, I believe this is a more standard option: https://jsonp.java.net/download.html
Usage example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an older question, but I have implemented a really simple [JSON String Builder in C#](https://gist.github.com/914857) as part of my [Fluent Flot](https://github.com/codesoda/FluentFlot) project which could be quite easily ported.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has a very good fluent JSON builder; unfortunately, as far as I can tell, it's not a module but part of the bulk of the elasticsearch codebase, so it's not easily used without elasticsearch.

See for an example: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/index_.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with this but my jsonj library was designed for this usecase.

https://github.com/jillesvangurp/jsonj

```
JsonObject o=object(
    field("aList",array(
        1,
        2,
        object(field("meaningoflife",42)),
        "no more builder"))
    ),
    field("another", "element"),
    field("aSet",set(1,2,3),
    field("nestedlists",array(
       array(1,2),
       array(3,4)
     ))
);

String json=o.toString();
```

I use several static methods that you can statically import. The builder methods are polymorph, and use varargs. JsonObject, JsonArray, JsonSet, and JsonPrimitive behave in sane ways and support generics as well.